# Inputs are printed wrongly of template types in program

Tags: c++, templates

here is the code snippet of my program with templates. It has no errors but when I print, it generates wrong result. Please tell me where I am wrong and how can I resolve this issue. Following is the C++ code having three functions and a main function with template T.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void input(T* &start, int size){
    start = new T[size];
    T* beyond = &start[size];

    while(start != beyond){
        cout<<"\nEnter: ";
        cin>>*start;
        start++;
    }
}


template<typename T>
void sort(T* start, int size){
    T hold;

    for(int j=0; j<size-1; j++){
        for(int i=0; i<size-1; i++){
            if(start[i]>start[i+1]){
                    hold=start[i];
                    start[i]=start[i+1];
                    start[i+1]=hold;
            }
        }
    }
}


template<typename T>
void display(T* start, int size){
    T* beyond = &start[size];
    cout<<"\nAfter Sorting: "<<endl;

    while(start != beyond){
        cout<<*start<<"\t";
        start++;
    }
}

int main(){
    int* x=NULL;
    float* y=NULL;
    char* z=NULL;
    int size;

    cout<<"Enter the number of elements: ";
    cin>>size;

    cout<<"\nEnter integer values:";
    input<int>(x, size);
    sort<int>(x, size);
    display<int>(x, size);

/** 
    cout<<"\nEnter floating values:";
    input<float, int>(y, size);
    sort<float, int>(y, size);
    display<float, int>(y, size);

    cout<<"\nEnter character values:";
    input<char, int>(z, size);
    sort<char, int>(z, size);
    display<char, int>(z, size);
    */
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: "generates wrong result" what is the wrong result? What is the right result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `input` function you allocate memory and put it to `start`. Then you move that pointer to the end and that end value will be returned to the calling function. Then you try to use that as the start to the other methods, which will lead to undefined behaviour.

```
template<typename T>
void input(T* &start, int size){
    start = new T[size]; // points to the start
    T* beyond = &start[size];

    while(start != beyond){
        cout<<"\nEnter: ";
        cin>>*start;
        start++; // Moving all the time...
    }
    // In the end start points to beyond and main gets that as a result
}
```

If you really want to play with pointers, you can fix it easily:

```
template<typename T>
void input(T* &start, int size){
    start = new T[size];
    T* beyond = &start[size];
    T* curr = start;

    while(curr != beyond){
        cout<<"\nEnter: ";
        cin>>*curr;
        curr++;
    }
}
```

This way the `start` pointer will always point to the beginning and is returned properly to the calling function.

Running step by step in debugger would show this problem easily. Also, please always describe the problem, we have no idea what "generates wrong result" means, if you don't explain what the right result would be or what you get as a result instead with certain input.

Comment: sorry sir, i didnt understood what you said. may you please give me code example for this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
template<typename T>
void input(T* &start, int size){
    start = new T[size];
    //T* beyond = &start[size-1];

    //while(start <= beyond){
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        cout<<"\nEnter: ";
        cin>>start[i];
        //start++;
    }
    //}
}
```

And:

```
template<typename T>
void display(T* start, int size){
    //T* beyond = &start[size-1];
    cout<<"\nAfter Sorting: "<<endl;

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        cout<<start[i]<<"\t";
    }
}
```

This is a simpler form to do what you are trying to do, and works.

Comment: this doesnt work. "size-1" eliminates 1 more value to be entered while taking input. I compiled.

Comment: No, this is not a problem. Beyond is calculated correctly as one step after the array.

Comment: start[i] with for loop is an old fasion. i want to increment the pointer address.

Comment: @SaveraChughtai There is nothing "old fashion" about it. And as you can see, fiddling with pointers just gave you a headache

Comment: despite that for loop, what was the actual problem with my program? why it is giving amazing results? plz